# How to work around GetEnumerator postponed call?

Tags: c#, .net, collections

I have simple code with intent to return enumerator over a file or a database if a file does not exist or the version of the data in it is out of date. Simple. However I am struggling with how the method works. Here is why:

```
public override IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetEnumerator()
{
    try
    {
        return GetFromFiles(); // returns instantly here
    }
    catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
    {
        return GetFromBackingStore();
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return GetFromBackingStore();
    }
}
```

And `GetFromFiles` looks like this:

```
private IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> GetFromFiles()
{
    foreach (var path in _paths)
    {
        using (var fs = _versioner.TryOpen(path))
        {
            var reader = _serializerFactory.CreateSerializer(fs, FileAccess.Read);

            KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> pair;
            while (reader.Read(out pair))
            {
                yield return pair;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when `GetEnumerator` is called using foreach, it returns instantly without executing `GetFromFiles` call first but then it does comeback to `GetFromFiles` method but now `try-catch` is already not in play so if `TryOpen` throws, exception is not handled. I am trying to understand why and how to work around it. It must be related to `yield return` I think and if this is the case, is there a way to do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first method you have, which includes the try/catch returns a reference to the second method, so it's only called once. Each time the outer code enumerate through, it doesn't call the first method again because it already have a reference to the enumerator, and therefore it calls it directly. You need to either move the try/catch to the second method, or use a standard collection that gets all initialized once instead of reading the elements one at a time. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Iterator blocks have deferred execution. In some cases, you can refactor ("extract method") the central part of the iterator block, so you do core tests immediately and only defer the iteration, but that is not possible here since you are doing an outer `foreach` (in particular, you could only really pre-emptively check the first file, unless you open them all).

Maybe the easiest thing, if the sizes are moderate, is to add `.ToList()` to do the whole thing now:

```
return GetFromFiles().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the `yeild` operator and the fact the inside the try catch was enumerator not executed. This part:

try
{
    return GetFromFiles(); // just a promise
}

is returning the Enumerator as a **promise**. There was no explicit iteration executed yet over `IEnumerable<>`. The yield acts as a *future*. It will be executed later when the .ToList() or .Count() .. is called...